# Finding which task went to which queue

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using RabbitMQ with Celery and I have set some custom routing settings for the task. A specific type of task goes to one queue and all the other tasks goes to another queue. Now I want to verify it is working or not.

For this, I want to inspect which tasks went to which queue. Unfortunately, I didn't find anything which could help me on this. celeryev monitor just provides information about which tasks have been received and what is their completion status. rabbitmqctl gives me information about the current running and waiting tasks only - so I cannot see to which queue did my intended task go to.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally can't inspect messages on a queue with AMQP (not sure about Celery, though).

If you just need this as a one-off test, the simplest way would probably be to write a quick program in Python that gets all messages from the queues and prints them out.

Using [py-ampqlib](http://barryp.org/software/py-amqplib/), this should do it:

```
from amqplib import client_0_8 as amqp

conn = amqp.Connection(host="localhost:5672", userid="guest", password="guest", virtual_host="/", insist=False)
chan = conn.channel()

queue_name = "the_queue"

print "Draining", queue_name

while True:
    msg = chan.basic_get(queue_name)
    if msg is None:
        break
    print msg.body

print "All done"
```

If you need more help, a good place to ask is the [RabbitMQ Discuss](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) mailing list.  The RabbitMQ developers do their best to answer all the questions posted there, and Celery's author also reads it.

Comment: Thanks. The information you provided was very useful for my ongoing task - though not specifically for this question. We changed the requirements a little bit and all I wanted to check was whether the routing was taking place correctly. This I did by queuing tasks but with my consumer / broker not UP. So the jobs were placed in the queue and then I checked them via rabbitmqctl -list_queues which proved whether my routing was correct (incorrect, in my case!) or not. py-ampqlib helped me in my other task which was checking whther my Server-Density config with RabbitMQ was correct or not. Thanks.